# Cannot install Laravel correctly

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php, vendor

I followed all the instruction by installing composer and then Laravel. Also I did everything what was shown in laracast series for installing Laravel and composer.
BUT I have some problems and I cannot solve them:

1. I don't have Vendor folder in my Laravel app folder
2. I cannot launch command 'composer artisan' as it says that

   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
   Command "artisan" is not defined"
3. "php artisan" also doesn't work
4. All the answer in the web I have already tried to resolve my problems but nothing worked for me

Please, tell me, how can I install Laravel correctly and use it without errors

Comment: Sounds like it didn't install all the way. What command did you use to create your project?

Comment: First I tried 'laravel new blog'and then 'composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog'

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What was the messages you got with each try when you tried to create a new project?

Comment: I created project normally without explicit errors, but when I try to run `composer artisan` it says
`[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "artisan" is not defined. `

`composer install` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I've solved my problem. As I mentioned before I had tried all the answer in the web but nothing had helped me. So then I just deleted my laravel project and ran this command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After some time packages were upgraded and I created new Laravel project. And Laravel started working perfectly! So in any incomprehensible situation do `apt-get upgrade` :))

Answer (score 2):

Run `composer install` or `composer update`. This will create the vendor folder and download all the dependent modules as mentioned in the composer.json

Comment: Do you get any error when you run composer install? If yes, whats the error? If no, do you see the dependent modules under vendor folder? Also if you can provide your composer.json, it can help to find any missing modules that you may need to include.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some more details which are asked but not clearly answered.

1. You did not install the composer dependencies. Try `composer install`.
2. It is not `composer artisan`. If you execute that command, you say hey composer! run your artisan command. And it says "*Command "artisan" is not defined.*"
3. It is `php artisan`. But if you don't run composer install, `php artisan` will not work either. Because you are missing `Symfony Console Component` in your project (not the one used by composer) as well as a complete Laravel installation. Both will also be installed by the `composer install` command.

Comment: `composer install` doesn't work. I run both `composer install` and `composer update`, but it still says `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "artisan" is not defined.  `

Probably I have to add something in composer.json file?